# Find a rule for the sequence $55, 176, 539, 1628, \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Would someone please show me how to write a rule for this sequence.

I understand how $a_{n+1}=3 a_{n} + 11$ but worked it out by a sort of mental approximation, which I find uncomfortable.

Would you please show me a reliable method for working out how to get from one term to the other, and how to write a rule so that I could find, say the 100th term.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sequence such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},u_{n+1}=au_n+b$ are called arithmetico-geometric sequence and one has a closed formula to express $(u_n)$. If $a\neq 1$, one has $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},u_n=a^n\left(u_0-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)+\frac{b}{1-a}$.

Comment: A first step is always to look at the differences between each term

Comment: $121 * 3^0$, $121 * 3^1$, $121 * 3^2$ - can you spot a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 11$

$a_{n+2} = 3(3a_n + 11) + 11 = 3^2a_n + 3*11 + 11$

$a_{n+3} = 3(3^2a_n + 3*11 + 11) + 11 = 3^3a_n + (3^2 + 3 + 1)11$

I see a pattern forming

$a_{n + k} = 3^ka_n + 11\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$

We can prove this by induction via

$a_{n + k + 1} = 3(a_{n + k}) + 11$

$= 3(3^ka_n + 11\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}) + 11$

$= 3^{k+1}a_n + 11\frac{3^{k+1} -3}{2} + 2*11/2$

$= 3^{k+1}a_n + 11\frac{3^{k+1} -1}{2} $

So plug in $a_0 = 55$ to get

$a_n = 3^n(55) + 11\frac{3^{n+1} -1}{2}= 11(5*3^n + \frac{3^{n+1} -1}{2})$

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know about Sheol's arithmetico-geometric sequences.

Answer (score 1):

**How to find $x_{100}$?**

Telling my friend Ruby a recursive function

```
def x(k)
  (k == 1) ? 55 : 3*x(k-1) + 11
end
```

she replies with:

```
> x(100)
=> 10393446668095561842568632783606695666159168360348
> x(100).to_s.length
=> 50
```

This agrees quite good with sheol's formula from the comment:

```
> 3**99*(55-11.0/(1-3)) + 11.0/(1-3)
=> 1.0393446668095562e+49
```

**How to find a rule behind an integer sequence?**

In today's age the use of a search engine is worth a try. A specialized search engine is [OEIS](http://oeis.org). Another one is [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=55%2C%20176%2C%20539%2C%201628). Next stop would be the two biggies, Google and Bing.

In this instance, WolframAlpha was able to recognize it, see the section "Possible sequence identification" and also try the "More" button.

The MathWorld article on [Integer Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerSequence.html) describes some techniques how to do it.

BTW: I vaguely remember a computer algebra book called something like "$A(k) = B(k)$", but my memory might be wrong, I can only spot the book "$A = B$" on identities and the images of the title pages do not match my memory.